# Kaminari Pagination TypeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kaminari

I`m using kaminari in rails 7 to make the apgination of my API, but when i try to see a page different of the first page, im taking a type error, when i try access "http://localhost:3000/products?page=3":

```
 TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer)
```

My paginated products index:

```
# GET /products
  def index
    page_number = params[:page].try(:[], :number)
    per_page = params[:page].try(:[], :size)


    @products = Product.all.page(page_number).per(per_page)

    paginate json: @products
  end
```

Anyone has a clue to how solve this?

EDIT:
I created a initializer named `api_pagination.rb` and put on him:

```
ApiPagination.configure do |config|
  config.page_param do |params|
    params[:page][:number] if params[:page].is_a?(ActionController::Parameters)
  end
    
  config.per_page_param do |params|
    params[:page][:size] if params[:page].is_a?(ActionController::Parameters)
  end
end
```

And now i can access "http://localhost:3000/products?page%5Bnumber%5D=2&page%5Bsize%5D=12" , but it doesn't look right to me, or this is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set default values? Try with:

```
page_number = params[:page].try(:[], :number) || 1
per_page = params[:page].try(:[], :size) || 20
```

if that doesn't work, check what's coming in those `number` and `size` params or share more information of your issue, like the whole error stacktrace, even better the full request log.

Comment: I put the default value, and now i`m taking this: 

#<NoMethodError: undefined method `to_i' for #<ActionController::Parameters {\"number\"=>\"2\", \"size\"=>\"12\"} permitted: false>\n\n      options[:page]     = options[:page].to_i\n                                         ^^^^^\nDid you mean?  to_s\n               to_h>"